# How to get this interface in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gui

I've wondered this for a while now.  Whenever I see any official Ubuntu images, I always see at least one with the following tablet interfaces:

[image]

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 the other day, and I'm wondering why I don't see that cool interface.  Not many options to play around with in the Settings app either :/

Is there a way to get this interface?  Or is it only available on tablets and phones? Or will it be available in the 14.10 or later releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Unity 8 Desktop, which shall be standard with the release of Ubuntu 16.04. You can already try it out, see here:
http://mhall119.com/2014/10/unity-8-desktop/

Comment: Wow, dude... 16.04? Thanks for the link!

Comment: Since it's not super stable yet, will i be able to go back to my current Unity version?

Comment: You can/should try it as a live CD/USB stick, this will boot from your drive and not affect your current Ubuntu installation. This is also provided by the link in the answer. (At the very bottom of the page). The Unity 8 Desktop is meant for the mobile devices in first and I think we will see it very soon on the first smartphones in 2015.

Comment: If you are interested in Ubuntu for phones, I would check out the `Meizu MX4`, which will be the first pre-installed Ubuntu Phone in 2015.